# Unable to get context of class in ListAdapter class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download an image using picasso. But problem is I am not getting context of my class. I have tried to make constructor and setter getter but still not getting context. Instead getting context of `MainActivity.class`. Because I am using my constructor their. I am using it on a button click. You can see that in `getView()` method.

Here is my code

```
  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: What context do you want?

Comment: I want context in Toast and Picassa method to load and save image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried, all of the below things while calling this class,

```
getActivity();
getBaseContext();
this;
"Your class".this;
getApplicationContext();
```

or in your HomeEventListAdapter class

```
 android.R.id.context
```

Try with these things.

Use this in your class

```
class HomeEventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   Context context;

   //constructor
   public HomeEventListAdapter(Context context){
     this.context=context;
   }
}
```

While calling HomeEventListAdapter from an activity class(Which extends AppCompactActivity or Activity)

```
HomeEventListAdapter adapter=new HomeEventListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

if "getApplicationContext()" not works, try other things which i have given.
I will give you context.

Comment: Yes I do. I am not extending my class with Activity.

Comment: no not extending, when you create an object of this class, from any activity class. Try it that time.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: But I want context in this class.

Comment: you have to pass it, then you will get.

Comment: Sorry. Its done now. I just not call .show() in toast. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

In `onBindViewHolder` you can access `context` like this:

```
holder.itemView.context
```